# Hide the filter bar on hidden columns in a plotly dash table

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I have a dash table that I have added a filter to the top of using `filter_action='native'`. However as I have a hidden column that I use for some conditional formatting (highlighting specific rows a given colour) I've noticed that the filter still appears for this column, even though both it and its header are hidden. Is there any way to remove this?

See below for a link to the screenshot of the hidden columns filter poking out at the end of the table.

https://ibb.co/Y2CVM6L

EDIT: including code snippet for creating the table.
Note that the column `whale_buy` is used for some conditional formatting but the display of it and the header are set to None (as I only want to use it for conditional formatting not to see that data). However the filter for it is still visible as seen in the attached screenshot.

````
                dash_table.DataTable(
                    id='sweep-table',
                    sort_action="native",
                    columns=[
                        {'name': ['', 'Name'], 'id': 'name'},
                        {'name': ['', 'Link'], 'id': 'link_address','presentation':'markdown'},
                        {'name': ['', 'Value'], 'id': 'spend'},
                        {'name':['','Count'],'id':'count'},
                        {'name':['','Number Bought'], 'id':'number_bought'},
                        {'name':['','Whales Bought'], 'id':'whale_buy'}
                    ],
                    filter_action='native',
                    style_filter={
                                'color': 'white'
                            },
                    data=[],
                    page_size=30,
                    style_as_list_view=True,
                    style_cell={
                        'textAlign': 'center',
                        'background-color': '#484848','color': '#FFFFFF',
                        'padding': '5px','maxWidth': '300px',
                        'overflow': 'hidden','textOverflow': 'ellipsis',
                    },
                    style_header={
                        'textAlign': 'center', 'fontWeight': 'bold',
                        'background-color': '#000000','color': '#FFFFFF',
                    },
                    style_data_conditional=[
                        {'if': {'row_index': 'odd'}, # for stripey rows
                        'background-color': '#383838'},
                        {'if': { 'filter_query': '{whale_buy} > 0',
                            },'background-color': '#FFD700','color': '#000000'},
                        {'if': {'column_id': 'whale_buy',},
                            'display': 'None',}
                    ],
                    style_header_conditional=[
                    {'if': {'column_id': 'whale_buy',},
                            'display': 'None',}
                    ]
                ),
            ])```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you include the code you've used to produce this plot? that would help us help you

Comment: @DerekO hey, my bad. Included a functional code snippet now. That broke the embedded image so I've included it again with a link